# How to compare two strings containing numbers in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

For example , I would like to compare  0-91 and 0-93 , in the logic I'm using , 0-93 is bigger than the 0-91 because I'm only looking at the numbers after 0-, which are 91 and 93 . Basically I'm building a form where it checks for ranges of numbers but in the form , the numbers could be typed in for example as 91 and 93 , but they are usually typed in as 0-91 and 0-93 , how can I write the javascript logic so that the 0- is ignore while comparing the two numbers ?

Basically convert 0-91 and 0-93 into integers 91 and 93 , then compare them.

Comment: Are the numbers always going to be in the form `0-x`?

Comment: `"0-93".match(/0-(\d+)/)[1]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want support for:

- Range or no range ("0-93" or "93")
- More or less digits ("0-999" or "9")

This is one way to solve it:

```
function numberFromInput(value) {
  return Number(value.match(/[-]?(\d*)$/).pop());
}

Math.max(numberFromInput("91"), numberFromInput("0-93"));
```

Comment: Thanks much Sven , so wthat would control either 91 or 0-93 .. but they would still be strings ?  to make them integers I would have to add the parseInt in the function parseInt(Number(value.match(/[-]?(\d*)$/).pop())); ?

Comment: There are no integers in JavaScript, just Numbers! You can test this with `1.0 === 1`. `parseInt` will also return a Number (with everything after the coma tossed away).

Comment: `parseInt(Number(...))` is redundant. Just use `parseInt`.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it would be :

```
var a = '0-91',
    b = '0-93',
    max = Math.max(a.slice(2), b.slice(2)), // for example
    max2 = Math.max(a.substr(-2), b.substr(-2)); // will work if a = "91" and b = "93"
```

Hope this helps

Comment: and that would produce 91 and 93 .. Would they be of integer type though or still string ?

Comment: a.slice(2) would still be a "string", but parseInt(a.slice(2), 10); would be a "number"

Comment: This solution will not work when the user inputs just 93. You could parse the string with regular expressions. Something like this: `"0-91".match(/[-]?(\d*)$/).pop()` will return "93".

Comment: Edited my answer, it works with substr(-2); But using a regex will work with more than 2 digits.

Comment: @SvenI see .. so I should just use .match(/[-]?(\d*)$/).pop()  for either 93 or 0-93 ??

Comment: @TDeBailleul, How can I check that if the string contains 0-93 .. use the method you describe , if it's just , then use the other method .. how can I do that in javascript ?

Comment: @JBa Yes, if you want support for input that is not a range.

Comment: @TDeBailleul Yeah, and with less than two digits. :)

Comment: Then Sven's answer is more appropriate